# When data is sent over a Socket, when does send/write returns -1?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

Linux. Tcp socket.

When does a send()/write() command fail?

Does it return -1 only if the TCP send buffer in the kernel overflow?

Comment: -1 in programs and programming in general usually indicates a runtime error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [OpenGroup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html) definition for write():

> Upon successful completion, write()
>   [XSI]   and pwrite()  shall return the
>   number of bytes actually written to
>   the file associated with fildes. This
>   number shall never be greater than
>   nbyte. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned
>   and errno set to indicate the error.

The same thing is done for send() - [OpenGroup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/send.html) page for send()

You will find out more information by looking at the errno. See the [OpenGroup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html) page on errno for some more information.

Comment: what is succesful completion here? writing the data to the kernel buffer or TCP receives an ack for the data form the remote side?

Comment: Success is writing to the kernel buffer.

Comment: @Blacklabel - from the send() page: "Successful completion of a call to send() does not guarantee delivery of the message. A return value of -1 indicates only locally-detected errors."

Answer (score 0):

To your specific point - if your write call was *blocking*, (as is the default), an overflow would just *block* you until there was buffer space available.

If the write call was *non-blocking*, and the buffers were full, you *would* receive an error.